# SQL Column not equal to string

Tags: sql-server-2008

In a stored procedure I want to check if a column value is not equal to a string, but not seem to work and I get syntax error.

This is what I am trying,

```
WHERE Table.ColumnName != "someText"
```

I also tried,

```
WHERE Table.ColumnName IS NOT LIKE "string"
```

**Error**:

> Invalid column name 'someText'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the double quotes `"` with single quotes `'` - then both snippets *should* work just fine.

```
WHERE Table.ColumnName != 'someText'
```

or

```
WHERE Table.ColumnName <> 'someText'
```

or

```
WHERE Table.ColumnName IS NOT LIKE 'someText'
```

What is the **datatype** of your column? If it's `NVARCHAR`, you might need to use a `N` prefix to signal Unicode: `WHERE Table.ColumnName <> N'string'`

Answer (score 0):

Use `<>`, Replace " with single quotes ' Problem Identifier marc_s thanks

```
WHERE Table.ColumnName <> 'string' or Table.ColumnName is null
```

Also i think `for not like`

```
where Table.ColumnNamenot like '%string%'
```